# How to use Bootstrap affix with large sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My sidebar is large and doesn't fit in my window. When I scroll down and reach bottom of sidebar, it sticks to window bottom and goes down with content, and when I scroll up, sidebar must scroll to its top, stick to window top, and go to the top of page.

I tried to use:

```
<aside data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="590">
...
</aside>
```

but it sticks to bottom, and when I scroll up, it stays fixed until sidebar reaches top of page.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting `data-offset-bottom="200"` as well?

Comment: no it did`t help. the sample is here http://klaipeda14.96.lt/test

Comment: In your case I would go with `position: sticky` solution. It is not widely supported and you will need a third party plugin to make it work in most browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky. The plugin I use mostly is https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill, but obviously you can google for more